# Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes

Tags: docker, scala, playframework, dockerfile, sbt

I used dockerfile below to build play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial(https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial)
I want to build the tutorial by dockerfile, but got an error like downloading issue. I wonder whether this is issue with network or dockerfile.

```
FROM openjdk:11

ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV HULU_ENV=staging

ADD . /play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial
WORKDIR /play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial
RUN curl -L https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.5.2/sbt-1.5.2.tgz -o sbt.tgz
RUN tar xf sbt.tgz

RUN ./sbt/bin/sbt clean stage
```

but got error below and failed to build

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile

#11 0.595 copying runtime jar...                                                                                             
#11 69.16 [warn]    Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
#11 69.16 [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine:1.2.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
#11 69.16 [warn]        org.foundweekends.giter8:sbt-giter8-scaffold:0.11.0 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
#11 69.16 [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.5.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
#11 69.16 [warn]        com.lightbend.sbt:sbt-javaagent:0.1.5 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
#11 69.16 [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-twirl:1.5.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
#11 69.16 [warn]        com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web:1.4.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
#11 69.16 [warn] 
#11 69.16 [warn]    Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
#11 69.25 [error] Error downloading org.foundweekends.giter8:sbt-giter8-scaffold;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.11.0
#11 69.25 [error]   Not found
#11 69.25 [error]   Not found
#11 69.25 [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/foundweekends/giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold_2.12_1.0/0.11.0/sbt-giter8-scaffold-0.11.0.pom
#11 69.25 [error]   not found: /root/.ivy2/localorg.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml
#11 69.25 [error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml
#11 69.25 [error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441337/scala-play-some-unresolved-dependencies-have-extra-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error is:

> download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml

SBT is not able to connect to the repository to download the dependencies because of some HTTPS issue.

This can be caused by several things, either because your container doesn't have proper certificates or because your running behind a corporate proxy maybe and it mess with certificates.

You should be able to find more help by searching on the `SSLHandshakeException` error.